# First function in code executing, but code following the first function is not executed

Tags: c, executable

My code executes the first function, but anything after the first function is not executed. I compiled using `gcc -o -Wall` and received no error messages.

when I tried to execute the code, I receive the execution at the bottom. I am not sure why the program will not execute more of the code. In the first function I can add more to the function to make work but it won't touch the other functions.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 //functions prototypes
  3 void compute_discount(void);
  4 int print_results(void);
  5
  6
  7 //defined Gloabal var
  8 double Mdisc;
  9 double Cost_of_purchase;
 10 double DiscTot;
 11 double Sales_tax;
 12 double Total_price;
 13 char military;
 14
 15 int main (void) {
 16     //declare variables
 17
 18     //Cost of purchase
 19     printf("Cost of purchase?\t\t$");
 20     scanf ("%lf",&Cost_of_purchase);
 21
 22     //Military?
 23     printf("In military (y or n)?\t\t\n");
 24     scanf("%s",&military);
 25
 26 }
 27
 28
 29 //function to compute discount
 30 void compute_discount(void){
 31
 32     //compute military discount
 33     switch(military){
 34     case 'y':
 35     case 'Y':
 36         if(Cost_of_purchase > 150) {
 37             Mdisc = .15 * Cost_of_purchase;
 38         } else if (Cost_of_purchase < 150) {
 39             Mdisc = .10 * Cost_of_purchase;
 40         }
 41         break;
 42     case 'n':
 43     case 'N':
 44         Mdisc = 0;
 45         break;
 46     default:
 47         printf("Error:bad input");
 48 }
 49
 50     //cost minus military discount
 51     DiscTot = Cost_of_purchase - Mdisc;
 52     //sales tax
 53     Sales_tax = .05 * DiscTot;
 54     //Total Calculated
 55     Total_price = DiscTot + Sales_tax;
 56
 57     printf("maybe this is the problem%f",Mdisc);
 58 }
 59
 60 //function to print results
 61 int print_results(void){
 62
 63     //if input is n N y Y then use below, this is not dependant on if military only if the letter is accepted
 64     switch(military){
 65     case 'y':
 66     case 'Y':
 67     case 'n':
 68     case 'N':
 69         printf("Military discount (15%%): \t\t$%f", Mdisc);
 70         printf("Discounted total: \t\t$%f", DiscTot);
 71         printf("Sales tax (5%%): \t\t$%f", Sales_tax);
 72         printf("Total: \t\t$%f", Total_price);
 73         break;
 74 }
 75 return(0);
 76 }
```

Result of execution:

```
[p18d541@csci112 lab1]$ gcc -o lab1 -Wall lab1.c
[p18d541@csci112 lab1]$ ./lab1
Cost of purchase?               $500
In military (y or n)?
y
[p18d541@csci112 lab1]$
```

I am wondering what more needs to be done to fix this issue, or what ways I can use to make the program execute those functions other than `int main()`.

Comment: You need to call the functions in main().

Comment: `scanf("%s")` asks to read a whole string, but you've only given it a pointer to a single `char`.  You probably want to use `%c` instead.

Comment: i changed that, but it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

```
scanf("%s",&military);
```

You're passing the address of a single `char`.  While the `%s` format specifier expects a `char *` parameter which is what is being passed, it also expects it to point to the first byte of an array so that it may store a string.  Because of this, the function attempts to write more than one byte when only one byte is available.  Writing past the bounds of an object triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

This can be fixed by using the `%c` format specifier which is for reading a single `char`.  You'll also need to add a space before it to consume the newline that the prior `scanf` left in the input buffer:

```
scanf(" %c",&military);
```

You also never called `compute_discount` and `print_results`, so you need to do that after reading the user's input.

```
int main (void)
{
    printf("Cost of purchase?\t\t$");
    scanf ("%lf",&Cost_of_purchase);

    //Military?
    printf("In military (y or n)?\t\t\n");
    scanf(" %c",&military);

    compute_discount();
    print_results();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow. thank you so much. i had no idea you had to call those. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You defined functions you want to use, but you are not calling these functions at all. Imagine a scenario, where you wanted to define a function to sum two numbers, `int a` and `int b`, and then call the function to count the sum. It would be:

```c
int sum(int a, int b) { 
    return a + b; 
}

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;

    printf("result: %d\n", sum(a, b));
    //                     ^^^^^^^^^
    //                     call sum function
}
```

It means that after defining the function, you need to use it, so your `main` would be:

```c
int main (void) {
    printf("Cost of purchase?\t\t$");
    scanf ("%lf",&Cost_of_purchase);
     
    printf("In military (y or n)?\t\t\n");
    scanf("%s",&military);

    // Finally call your defined functions:
    compute_discount();
    print_results();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other functions (besides `main`) are not executed because they are never called. `main` is called automatically when you run the program, but any other functions must be explicitly called. Add calls to `compute_discount` and `print_results` at the bottom of main, following the second `scanf`.

BTW, your second `scanf`is particularly dangerous, because you are using a `"%s"` format to read a single character... what happens if the user types in "yes"... where do the 'e' and the 's' go?